# Post to facebook like twitter

Tags: facebook

Is is possible to post something to facebook, like on twitter?

I mean when user click a link, like this https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://google.com&text=Hello%20world but for facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Use https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&t=Hello+World to post the same message to facebook.

Comment: It shares the link; but seems to be missing the message though.